# Any way to set the text shadow for a SpannableString?

Tags: android, textview, shadow, spannablestring

I've got an Android home screen widget, with a `TextView` on it.. Unfortunately, I'm having some issues styling it..

I want to apply a dynamic (changing from code) shadow to the text, and I'm not sure how to do this. I can set the shadow in the layout, but if I want to change it in code, there's no way to do this over a `RemoteView`!

I thought I could do this with a `SpannableString`, but I can't find anything useful.. If I use a `TextAppearanceSpan` in it, it will ignore the shadow attributes from the style. Furthermore, the moment I start using a `SpannableString` on a `TextView` it starts ignoring the shadow that I applies to the `TextView` :(

What's wrong with that, and what's my best course of action here?

Answer (score 0):

Edited: this won't work on widgets since custom views cannot be used there. But it might be of some help for someone trying to set it on a remote view somewhere else.

See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10029

---

A way of doing this would be to make a custom TextView called ShadowyTextView, with a method for each value I want to set.

Then is just a matter of writing something like:

> remoteViews.setInt(R.id.myShadowyText, "setShadowColor", someColor);

And so the attribute is set by reflection.

Maybe not the most elegant solution, but couldn't found anything better.

Answer (score -1):

Try with the following code

```
TextView textHello = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hello);
        textHello.setShadowLayer(
          5f,   //float radius
          10f,  //float dx
          10f,  //float dy 
          0xFFffffff //int color
          );
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as I pointed out, I'm in a widget, and changing stuff through a `RemoteView`, so I can't do that...